# Get Product Data from shopify GraphQL for over 10000 Products

Tags: rest, graphql, shopify, shopify-api

I have an extremely large selection of products in a collection (140,000), to get the data of 250 is fine but I need to get a list of tags for 140,000 products, I have created a bulkOperationRunQuery to get the data. Here is the query I use to run

```
mutation {
 bulkOperationRunQuery(
  query: """
  {
   products{
    edges{
      node{
        id
        tags
      }
    }
  }
}
   """
 ) {
bulkOperation {
  id
  status
}
userErrors {
  field
  message
}
}}
```

This Works but takes far to long to process, how can I make this quicker is there a set limit on the request

Comment: Bulk operations should be done once in a while. Like when you need to import products for the first time or you need to reprocess them for some reason. So my question is, why you need it to be faster? How often you need to do it?

Comment: Well maybe once a day, but I would only need this if importing the data to another server to handle the search the customers will use, what I really want is the customers to access this data on shopify with the Storefront api

Comment: The end goal is for the customer to go onto the shop page and see a list of products and then see how many products have a certain tag, so for example colour_blue is a tag and 12,000 products have that tag, I want to list saying that in the collection their are 12,000 products with this tag

Comment: I'm sorry if this doens't answer. A normal approach would be to search for the tag (with 250 product per page) and says "250+ products with this tag". 
If you're final goal is to display products to customers, I think the paginated result should be enough. The only downside of that is that sometimes you can't filter for certain fields (or metafields). But if that's not your case (tags are covered), pagination should be fine.
Solution 2, as you said in another comment, is that you create your own DB and live happily ever after.

Comment: Well it won't be "happily ever after" as I will have to set up a cron to run and get this data every time the products get updated, also when a product is sold I would have to update so it isnt really a solution

Comment: No, you just implement a webhook that updates the database every products/add or products/update. https://shopify.dev/api/admin-rest/2022-04/resources/webhook
It is in fact the solution that all the filters app apply. And I'm sure many others.

Answer (score 0):

That is all you get for a massive ask like that. If you have 140,000 products you ask for the once. Then you have them, and speed should be of little consequence. There is no need to repeat yourself by asking for them again and again. If you are interested in changes, just listen to product change webhooks. Save yourself a lot of grief that way.

Comment: But to get the initial count of how many blue products I have in stock this won't work, I will need to create another database to handle this request. also if their are products with tags that do not get into the first 1000 i cannot say that the collection has these products or I will have to display all tags and when the customer clicks on the filter 0 products return.

Comment: You get ALL your products. It is JSON data. Therefore, you can parse it, count it, and do all your logic. When you say it won't work, you are not being clear. I cannot speak for what you are doing, but apparently, if you cannot work with the data representing your store, you have other problems beyond the one you asked.